# angularjs:-Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] issue while running code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, popup

Hi I was trying to implement a pop up in angular but while doing so I am getting the error `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/$injector/modulerr?p0=PopupDemo&p1=Error%…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.9%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)`

The below is the code I have written.

```
     <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="PopupDemo">
<div ng-controller="PopupDemoController">
<a ng-click="open()">Open Popup</a>
</div>

    <script>
        angular.module('PopupDemo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
        angular.module('PopupDemo')
                .controller('PopupDemoController',['$scope','$modal',function ($scope, $modal) {

        $scope.open = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'first.html',
        });
}
}]);
    </script>
</body>
```

I am not sure why I am getting the error and what is the way out..Not getting any sort of help from online resources and angular website..

I do know there is some module which is missing in the file,But not sure how to check for it.

Can someone please help me out..Am getting stuck in this.

Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Download your "ui.bootsrap" files from here http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code should probably work.

- Have added bootstrap.ui js
- Changed the Module name accordingly

Code:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.1/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="PopupDemo">
<div ng-controller="PopupDemoController">
    <a ng-click="open()">Open Popup</a>
</div>

<script>
    var myMod = angular.module('PopupDemo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    myMod.controller('PopupDemoController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', function($scope, $modal) {

        $scope.open = function() {
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl: 'first.html',
            });
        }
    }]);
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Update:

You are missing ui.bootstrap.js file. please include that. It is not suffice to include bootstrap.js.

Also, please use $uibModal instead of $modal

```
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', function($scope, $uibModal) {
            $scope.hi = "hello world"; 

            $scope.open = function() {
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    template: '<h1>Hello world</h1>',
                });
            }
        }]);
```

JQuery js should come before bootstrap js. Could you please try that

Comment: I am not sure how that will help..I am not even started to work with bootstrap..Anyways done it and still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace with this code

```
<script>
    var app = angular.module('PopupDemo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    app.controller('PopupDemoController', ['$scope', '$modal',    function($scope, $modal) {
            $scope.open = function() {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'first.html',
                });
            }
        }]);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you didnt load the [ui.bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) module 
you can use [this cdn](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular-ui-bootstrap)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you also need to add angular bootsrap-ui reference:
For example:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.2.1/ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
```